# How to make a file or folder undeletable?

Tags: files, directory

I want to make a file or folder undeletable, even the superuser can't be able to delete that file.`Chattr` command makes a file undeletable only if the files were in Linux filesystems (`ext2,ext4`). But I want to make a file undeletable which was present in `ntfs` filesystem.

Answer (score 21):

**There is not such thing that "`root`" can't delete.** Is like telling God that he cannot do or undo something. `root` can put your machine topsidedown and make 1+1=3 if it likes and you can't do anything to prevent it. So, **you can't prevent root from deleting whatever file he likes, just can't.** Nor NTFS, nor ext2/3/4, nor HSF+, nor FAT16/32/64 not any other filesystem ruled by the OS.

#### The long and boring answer

Unless nobody else has `root` access to your system, this **is impossible**. But then there are ways that make users going a step beyond to delete the file, one of these is `chattr`:

> chattr changes the file attributes on a Linux file system.
>
> [...]
>
> A file with the `i` attribute cannot be modified: it cannot be  deleted or  renamed,  no  link  can  be created to this file and no data can be written to the file.  Only the superuser or a  process  possessing  the `CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE` capability can set or clear this attribute.

So, **if nobody has `root` access or capacity to boot using another operative system then the file is undeletable, otherwise any user can (and will) delete your file.** The same if the filesystem is formatted and/or firmware techniques to remove data of the disks.

#### How to do it?

Create the file:

```
$ touch deletemeifyoucan
```

Protect it:

```
$ sudo chattr +i deletemeifyoucan 
[sudo] password for braiam:
```

Try to remove it

```
$ rm deletemeifyoucan
rm: remove write-protected regular empty file ‘deletemeifyoucan’? y
rm: cannot remove ‘deletemeifyoucan’: Operation not permitted
```

Now try with root:

```
$ sudo rm deletemeifyoucan 
rm: cannot remove ‘deletemeifyoucan’: Operation not permitted
```

Unprotect it:

```
$ sudo chattr -i deletemeifyoucan
```

Is gone:

```
$ rm deletemeifyoucan 
$ #POOF!
```

Comment: What is the `:D`? Surprisingly when I do `man chattr` I get nothing at all. Nor anything for `chattr --help`. Neither I was able to find anything from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chattr). My understanding is that it's just a colon in your file name, which is super confusing :/

Comment: `chattr` is GNU/Linux, `chflags` is BSD/Mac. The equivalent of making a directory immutable is `sudo chflags -R schg "$folder"`

Comment: @Honey it's part of the name of the file.

Comment: don't you think it's confusing?:D

Comment: It's worth noting that this doesn't show up in `ls` in any way, shape or form. In order to see the `immutable` flag, you'll need to use the `lsattr` command instead.

Comment: This is excellent thank you unlike the guys who suggest using "protect" but forget to tell the reader that it does NOT stop you from deleting a file from GUI. I lost an important file with protect
THis chattr here gives protection CLI AND GUI
Grateful for info thanx

Comment: PS although you still need to tell folks they cannot modify and save the file while it is on chattr +i.     

IMPORTANT needed info too

Comment: also maybe to tell them how to install chattr  
> sudo apt -y install e2fsprogs